# Electronic or electronics for the adjective

Tags: adjectives

Is it correct to say "electronics products" or "electronic products"?

Comment: it can also apply for "electronic factory" and "electronics factory". From Google search: electronic factory
About 107,000,000 results electronics factory
About 48,400,000 results

Answer (score 5):

There's a very, very slight difference in meaning: **electronic** refers, basically, to what's inside; essentially anything that uses electricity (rather than, say, steam), and is controlled by electrical signalling/switching rather than mechanical, is "electronic".  **Electronics**, on the other hand, refers to a class of products, generally intended for use by the public rather than by industry, and often for entertainment rather than utility.  The *[Consumer Electronics Association](http://www.ce.org/)*, which puts on the annual [Consumer Electronics Show](http://www.cesweb.org/) (better known as CES), is largely responsible for establishing and maintaining the distinction between the two, I think.

A CNC laser cutter is an electronic product; an iPod is an electronics product.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are perfectly okay. The second is over twice as common as the first, but there's no significant difference in meaning. Here's a chart of written usage...

[image: .]

Answer (score 1):

The difference between "electronic product" and "electronics product" is this:

> An "electronics product" is a product dealing with electronics, i.e. diode, or transistor, etc.
>
> An "electronic product" is a product that runs on electricity, i.e. An electronic toy, or calculator etc.

Comment: This (electronics product: something you get from Radio Shack or Mouser; electronic product: something you get at Best Buy) is how I parsed the difference as well, but I would be interested in seeing a more definitive reference.

Answer (score 0):

Either is correct, but "electronic products" is much more common; simply "electronics" is much, much more common even than that.

Comment: Bare 'electronics' can be other things too - field of study, for example. You need at least sufficient context to allow 'products' to be inferred if it's not explicitly specified.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, I suppose you're right. But without any particularly special context, I think it generally refers to products, at least in everyday speech.

Comment: Agreed it is the default. So really I guess I'd have to say that total lack of any other context constitutes sufficient 'product' context in and of itself. My second sentence wasn't one of the best I've ever written! :)